# Error in simple C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I get

> error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base()'

in code

```
class Base {
private:
     char *field;
public:
    Base(char *c){
        field = c;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(char *c){}
};
```

Error disappears as soon as I add

```
Base() {}
```

constructor. Why does the C++ compiler strictly require a `Base()` constructor with no arguments? What if creating a `Base` object with no arguments makes no sense?

P.S. For example, I do not have the same error in similar Java code because I would have to add

```
super("")
```

as a first statement of body of `Derived` constructor. And that is really reasonable.

Comment: "What if creating Base object with no arguments makes no sense?" then your `Derived` class makes no sense.

Comment: "*What if creating Base object with no arguments makes no sense?*" Well, then don't do that?

Comment: What where you thinking when posting this HTML cluttered mess? Stackoverflow handles the syntax highlighting very well if you give it a chance ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ doesn't require a default constructor in the base class -- but as in Java, you need to call the equivalent of Super, otherwise the compiler will attempt to call the default constructor (which you don't have, hence the error):

```
Derived(char *c) : Base(*c) { }
```

The bit after the `:` is called the *initializer-list*, and is most useful -- not only can you call base class constructors there, but you can initialize member variables (`: var(val), var2(val2)` syntax) that have non-default constructors.

Comment: Java doesn't require default constructor, too.

Comment: @user: Right, ambiguous wording on my part, sorry. I meant, in situations like this, you need to manually call the non-default base constructor, as you would in Java.

Answer (score 5):

> Why does C++ compiler strongly require Base() constructor with no arguments?

Because `Derived(char*)` attempts to call `Base()`, since you don't tell it to call any other constructor, which you can do like this:

```
 Derived(char *c) : Base('x') {}
```

or, using the `char` pointed at by the `Derived` constructor argument, and making sure not to de-reference a null pointer:

```
 Derived(char *c) : Base( c ? *c : 'x') {}
```

Comment: Good choice of character constant :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the base initializer:

```
Derived(char * c)  :  Base('x') { }
```

Comment: Good choice of character constant!

Answer (score 2):

Thsi is because

```
Derived(char *c){}
```

implicitly calls

```
Base()
```

unless you provide which constructor to call explicitly It is equivalent to

```
Derived(char *c) : Base() {}
                   ^^^^^^
```

And `Base::Base()` is not available since you have implemented your own constructor. Otherwise it would have been enabled by default. When you provide it explicitly the code complies. *but not doing what you want probably*.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Base` doesn't have a constructor that takes no arguments. You can either make one that does, or add an initalizer for the existing one:

```
 Derived(char *c) : Base('a') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you explictly create a constructor for Base, the compiler no longer generates a default ctor for you base. That is the reason why you are getting that error message. For example

```
class Base{}; //here compiler auto-generates 'Base(){}' for you

class Base2{ 
 Base2(char c){}
}; //here compiler does NOT auto-generate `Base2(){}` for you. 
   //Hence that constructor does not exist and you have to create it yourself
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does C++ compiler strongly require Base() constructor with no arguments?

It doesn't. It requires derived classes to use one of its constructors; if they don't provide any arguments, then it will try to use the default constructor.

> What if creating Base object with no arguments makes no sense?

Then the derived class will have to provide the argument(s) for the constructor it uses:

```
Derived(char *c) : Base(c) {}
```